# WPF Datepicker Calendar buttons not working (Using modified template)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, calendar, datepicker

I apologize in advance if this is already out there (I did an advanced search and couldn't find this specific issue.)

I'm using a custom WPF Datepicker calendar template (Just changing colors really), but now my buttons don't work. It will pop up the calendar, but nothing works from that point, Am i missing anything? Here's the code below:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=WPFToolkit" >
<Style x:Key="CalendarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE4EAF0" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFECF0F4" Offset="0.16"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFD" Offset="0.16"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <primitives:CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" Style="{DynamicResource CalenderStyleNew}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CalenderStyleNew" 
           TargetType="primitives:CalendarItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="primitives:CalendarItem">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <!-- Start: Data template for header button -->
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="DayTitleTemplate">
                        <TextBlock
                                            FontWeight="Bold" 
                                            FontFamily="Verdana" 
                                            FontSize="9.5" 
                                            Foreground="Black" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            Text="{Binding}"
                                            Margin="0,6,0,6"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <!-- End: Data template for header button -->
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="MonthTitleTemplate">
                        <TextBlock
                                            FontWeight="Medium" 
                                            FontFamily="Verdana" 
                                            FontSize="9.5" 
                                            Foreground="Red" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            Text="{Binding}"
                                            Margin="0,10,0,6"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                <Grid Name="PART_Root" >
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledColor" Color="#A5FFFFFF" />
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            CornerRadius="1">

                        <!-- This Brush is new -->
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0"   Color="#FFE4EAF0" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#FFECF0F4" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"   Color="#FFECF0F4" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>

                        <Border CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <!-- Start: Previous button template -->
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PreviousButtonTemplate" TargetType="{ x:Type Button}">
                                        <Grid Cursor="Hand">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF73A9D8" Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".5" Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Rectangle Fill="#11E5EBF1" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="1"/>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Path Margin="14,-6,0,0" Height="10" Width="6" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill" Data="M288.75,232.25 L288.75,240.625 L283,236.625 z">
                                                    <Path.Fill>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="TextColor" Color="#FF333333" />
                                                    </Path.Fill>
                                                </Path>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="NextButtonTemplate" TargetType="{ x:Type Button}">
                                        <Grid Cursor="Hand">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF73A9D8" Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".5" Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Rectangle Fill="#11E5EBF1" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="1"/>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Path Margin="0,-6,14,0" Height="10" Width="6" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="Fill" Data="M282.875,231.875 L282.875,240.375 L288.625,236 z">
                                                    <Path.Fill>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="TextColor" Color="#FF333333" />
                                                    </Path.Fill>
                                                </Path>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>

                                    <!-- End: Next button template -->

                                    <!-- Start: Header button template -->
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderButtonTemplate" TargetType="{ x:Type Button}">
                                        <Grid Cursor="Hand">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TextColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Blue" Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="buttonContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".5" Duration="0" />
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                            <!-- This Border is new -->
                                            <Border Padding="12 0"
                                                        CornerRadius="6">
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FF73A9D8" />
                                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF73A9E8" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Border.Background>

                                                <ContentPresenter
                                                    x:Name="buttonContent"
                                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                    Margin="1,4,1,9"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                                    <TextElement.Foreground>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="TextColor" Color="#FF333333"/>
                                                    </TextElement.Foreground>
                                                </ContentPresenter>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                    <!-- End: Header button template -->

                                </Grid.Resources>

                                <!-- Start: Previous button content -->
                                <Button x:Name="PART_PreviousButton" 
                                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                        Template="{StaticResource PreviousButtonTemplate}" 
                                        Height="20" Width="28" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                        Focusable="False"
                                        />
                                <!-- End: Previous button content -->

                                <!-- Start: Header button content -->
                                <Button x:Name="PART_HeaderButton"                                             
                                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                                        Template="{StaticResource HeaderButtonTemplate}" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                        Height="28" Width="110"
                                        FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10.5" 
                                        Focusable="False"
                                        />
                                <!-- End: Header button content -->

                                <!-- Start: Next button content -->
                                <Button x:Name="PART_NextButton" 
                                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                                        Height="20" Width="28" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                        Template="{StaticResource NextButtonTemplate}" 
                                        Focusable="False"
                                        />
                                <!-- End: Next button content -->

                                <!-- Start: Month Content Grid -->
                                <Grid x:Name="PART_MonthView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="Visible" Margin="6,-1,6,6">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                </Grid>
                                <!-- End: Month Content Grid -->

                                <!-- End: Year Content Grid -->
                                <Grid x:Name="PART_YearView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="6,-3,7,6">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                </Grid>
                                <!-- End: Year Content Grid -->
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Stroke="{StaticResource DisabledColor}" Fill="{StaticResource DisabledColor}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Value="Year">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <Binding Path="DisplayMode">
                                <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                    <RelativeSource Mode="FindAncestor" AncestorType="{x:Type Controls:Calendar}" />
                                </Binding.RelativeSource>
                            </Binding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_MonthView" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_YearView" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Value="Decade">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <Binding Path="DisplayMode">
                                <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                    <RelativeSource Mode="FindAncestor" AncestorType="{x:Type Controls:Calendar}" />
                                </Binding.RelativeSource>
                            </Binding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_MonthView" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_YearView" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*Note:* I've got this resource dictionary set at an application level and I'm globally binding the calendarstyle properties to all datepickers.

This is in an app level resource dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
  <Setter
        Property="CalendarStyle"
        Value="{StaticResource CalendarStyle1}" />
</Style>
```

And this is where the resource dictionaries are referenced (In case I did it wrong, I'm new to xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
                Source="ResourceDictionary/CustomCalendar.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary
                Source="ResourceDictionary/GlobalStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with your style TargetTypes. If you notice you have the style for your calendar defined as:

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
```

And the style for your CalendarItem defined as:

```
<Style x:Key="CalenderStyleNew" TargetType="primitives:CalendarItem">
```

The problem is that the Calendar type is from the standard System.Windows.Controls package but the CalendarItem is from the namespace Microsoft.Windows.Controls (that's the wpftoolkit namespace you have defined as `primitives`). So to fix this you have to either use ALL System.Windows.Controls in your styles or use ALL Microsoft.Windows.Controls namespaces.

I fixed your issue to use all Microsoft.Windows.Controls:

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:Calendar}">
```

The global styles must be changed to:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:DatePicker}">
    <Setter
    Property="CalendarStyle"
    Value="{StaticResource CalendarStyle1}" />
</Style>
```

And to instantiate a DatePicker you must use the correct one:

```
<Controls:DatePicker />
```

NOT

```
<DatePicker />
```

If you don't reference it from the WpfToolkit namespace it won't have your custom styles.

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: 8 months later, I have enough rep. Just wanted to let you know that I came back to upvote you :)